# Error : vue Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: vue.js

i'm building an app, i tried to do router for login page but it give me this error :

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4484 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, is there anything i did wrong

thank you for your help hopefully u can give me a hint on how to fix it

this is the Login Components

```
    <template>
      <div class="hello">
    Login
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: '',
      props: {
        msg: String
      }
    }
    </script>

    <!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
    <style scoped>

    </style>

Home Components

    <template>
      <div class="hello">
        <header class="globalNav noDropdownTransition">


      <div class="container-lg">
        <ul class="navRoot">


          <li class="navSection logo">
            <a class="rootLink item-home colorize" href="/"><h1>Charity Finder</h1></a>
          </li>

          <li class="navSection primary">
            <a class="rootLink item-products hasDropdown colorize" data-dropdown="products">
              Products
            </a>
            <a class="rootLink item-developers hasDropdown colorize" data-dropdown="developers">
              Developers
            </a>
            <a class="rootLink item-company hasDropdown colorize" data-dropdown="company">
              Company
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="navSection secondary">
            <a class="rootLink item-support colorize" href="">
              Support
            </a>
              <router-link class="rootLink item-dashboard colorize" to="/login">  Sign in</router-link>



          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>


    </header>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      props: {
        msg: String
      }
    }
    </script>

    <!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
    <style scoped>

    </style>
```

This the router Router

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: I think related to repeated navigation links loop, try check the missing/possible bugged routerLinks

Comment: Can you add the App.vue?